# "Cannot convert undefined or null to object" when setting props "onGridReady" or "rowSelection" (React)

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I tried to follow the steps on https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/

When I code like this:

```
<AgGridReact
 rowSelection="multiple"
....
```

or

```
<AgGridReact
   onGridReady={ params => this.gridApi = params.api } 
...
```

An Error occured:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at agGridColumn.js:63
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at Function.umi../node_modules/@ag-grid-community/react/lib/agGridColumn.js.AgGridColumn.assign (agGridColumn.js:62)
    at Function.umi../node_modules/@ag-grid-community/react/lib/agGridColumn.js.AgGridColumn.createColDefFromGridColumn (agGridColumn.js:55)
    at Function.umi../node_modules/@ag-grid-community/react/lib/agGridColumn.js.AgGridColumn.toColDef (agGridColumn.js:38)
    at agGridColumn.js:34
```

I checked the previous questions in [ag-grid] tag, it seems that no one has ever encountered this case.
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Need to add these lines also:-

```
<div style={{ height: '150px', width: '600px' }} className="ag-theme-balham">
 <button onClick={this.onButtonClick}>Get selected rows</button>
</div>
<AgGridReact
    onGridReady={ params => this.gridApi = params.api }
....
```

And define onButtonClick() method like this:-

```
onButtonClick = e => {
const selectedNodes = this.gridApi.getSelectedNodes()
const selectedData = selectedNodes.map( node => node.data )
const selectedDataStringPresentation = selectedData.map( node => node.make + ' ' + node.model).join(', ')
alert(`Selected nodes: ${selectedDataStringPresentation}`)
}
```

Inside this method, we accessed the grid api object reference to access the currently selected grid row nodes.([As per documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/))